# Handling errors at a global level

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am trying to understand how to build my error handling system for my api.

Let's say I have a the following line in a controller method :

```
  var age = json.info.age;
```

with

```
json = {"id":1, "name":"John", info": {"age":27, "sex":"m"}}
```

Let's say that the object doesn't contain an `info` field, I'll get the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined` and my server will crash.

Is there a way to make a higher level abstraction and catch all the potential errors that I could have? Or should I have a try/catch system for each of the methods of my controllers?

Comment: Try to improve your question for other users facing the same problem. Maybe by adding the skeleton of your controller and action, dummy data like `var MyController = { index: function(req, res){ // Add the code that can raise the exception here... } }`  so its easier to figure out what you are talking about.

Comment: You don't need a try/catch around every one of your controllers, but writing `var age = json.info.age` without checking that that is a valid object is just plain bad code.  You can either wrap that piece of code in a try/catch, or do `var age = json && json.info && json.info.age;`, and handle the case where `age` still ends up `undefined` by returning an error to the client.  Using a global error-handling system to catch this kind of a problem is just sloppy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**BEWARE OF THE CODE BELOW, IT WILL BITE YOU WHENEVER IT CAN!**

> Don't use the code snippet below if you do not understand its
>   implications, please read the whole answer.

---

You can use the node way for uncaught errors. Add this in your `config/bootstrap.js`

**Updated the snippet below to add what was said in the comments, also added a warning about using a global to respond to the user.**

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    // Handle your errors here

    // global.__current__ is added via middleware
    // Be aware that this is a bad practice,
    // global.__current__ being a global, can change
    // without advice, so you might end responding with 
    // serverError() to a different request than the one
    // that originated the error if this one happened async 
    global.__current__.res.serverError();
  })
```

Now, **can doesn't mean should**. It really depends on your needs, but do not try to catch **BUGS** in your code, try to catch at a controller level the issues that might not happen every time but are somehow expected, like a third-party service that responded with empty data, you should handle that in your controller. The `uncaughtException` is mainly for logging purposes, its better to let your app crash if there is a bug. Or you can do something more complicated (that might be better IMHO), which is to stop receiving requests, respond to the error 500 (or a custom one) to user that requested the faulty endpoint, and try to complete the other requests that do not relate to that controller, then log and shutdown the server. You will need several instances of sails running to avoid zero downtime, but that is material for another question. What you asked is how to get uncaught exceptions at a higher lvl than the controllers.

[I suggest you read the node guide for error handling](https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors)

[Also read about domains](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html), even thought they are deprecated you can use them, but you would have to deal with them per controller action, since sails does not provide any help with that.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I was looking for, but as you said, the uncaughtException is mainly for logging purposes, but can I send back a response to the user like res.serverError() (a generic 500 error)?

Comment: You can, but not in an straightforward way that i can think of atm, since you don't have access to the res object, but i guess that you can make the res obj a global on a policy that you can apply to all controllers, and that global should only be called by the 'uncaughtException' handler. Something among the lines of `global.__current__ = {req: req,res:res};`, then you'll have access to the res object of the request that triggered the error. But beware of what you are doing, you are walking on sand here. Good luck :)

Comment: I also though about using the sails.renderView() method. The idea behind that is to have my service working 24/7, even if there is an exception that I didn't think about. That would trigger an alarm based on a FATAL log so it could be corrected fast enough while the service is still up.

Comment: I haven't used that method, but if it works go ahead, its simpler. Good luck with that service :)

Comment: @Zagen, I am in a moral dilemma over whether to upvote this answer :)  Your commentary is spot-on, but I'm concerned that folks might just skip it and use your code snippet instead.

Comment: @sgress454 Then let me put an all caps advice on top now that the OP got his answer, so you can get out of your moral dilemma ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can check this way if you want to:

```
if (object != null && object.response != null && object.response.docs != null){
//Do your stuff here with your document
}
```

I don't really get what is your "object" variable in the first place, so i don't know if you can check it at a different level, is it a sails parameter to your controller ?

Comment: I edited the question : the object is a javascript object containing different fields, and one of them can be the "response" field, that field contains the "docs" field

Answer (score 0):

So that's how I did it, thanks to Zagen's answer.

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {

  process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    //Handle your errors here
    logger.fatal(err);
    global.__current__.res.serverError();
  })
  cb();
};
```

I send a generic error 500 to the user if any uncaught exception is thrown, and I log the error to the fatal level. On that way, my server is still accessible 24/7 and I can monitor the logs at another level and trigger an alarm on a fatal error. I can then fix the exception that was thrown.